# "Gel" to temporary stick to glass like surfaces like a mobile phone

Tags: material-science

I am developing a product to attach to a mobile phone temporarily. I have seen these giveaway screen cleaners. Small stickers you can put on the back of your mobile phone, easily remove them and clean the screen with some kind of micro fibre surface and then put it back on the back of the phone.

For example [Screen Daddy](https://scrubdaddy.com/screen-daddy-colors/) and there is a huge amount of different brands.

I am interested in the material used on the side that temporarily attaches to the phone without leaving any stains. Any idea on how to investigate this material? I have asked one of the manufacturers and they state it is some kind of PU material, but on other specifications I have seen it refered to like some kind of gel.

Comment: There are many grades of polyurethane from rock hard to dead soft so you'll have to just look into all of those.

Comment: So you expect a manufacturer to give you the benefit of their research and development? what do you offer in return?

Comment: @DKNguyen sounds like a tought thing to do. Also I guess any surface treatment would matter

Comment: @SolarMike well I see a lot of different manufacturers of similar kinds so I do not think it is a trade secret but rather some kind of off the shelf material. But I could be wrong of course.

Comment: You're probably going to approach a manufacturer and get samples or something. Or a supplier that sells lots of different materials to get samples from.

Answer (score 2):

In 2015, I purchased from UM Brands a product I thought to be "gecko adhesive sheet." It's a tough search term as so many false returns result from these terms. UM Brands has a [listing on the internet](http://www.thanksmailcarrier.com/2012/07/um-brands-reusable-adhesive-household.html) for products that match your description.

In the process of performing this search, I found from [UC Berkely a fairly technical document](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eronf/Gecko/index.html) describing some of the work in this line of "technology." Image below from linked site.

[image: gecko adhesive technology image]

I have a piece of the material I purchased attached to a flat-backed digital clock, stuck to a mirror. It's been there since 2015, but can be easily removed and replaced.